# how to save the user_id after using "create!" in rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller

I've recently updated my controller code to this for create

```
class MicropostsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :signed_in_user

   def create
  @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(params[:micropost])


  if @micropost.review
      params[:micropost].delete :review
      @thread = Discussion.create!(params[:micropost])    
    else
      @micropost.save

    end
    redirect_to root_path
  end
```

When I use the above, it seems to work as the Discussion or the Micropost gets created. However, I believe that using "create!" does not save the user_id. When I view the Discussions, the user_id is nil. How can I save the user_id with whoever made the post?

Tables in schema.db

```
create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string    "name"
    t.string    "email"
    t.timestamp "created_at",                         :null => false
    t.timestamp "updated_at",                         :null => false
    t.string    "password_digest"
    t.string    "remember_token"
    t.boolean   "admin",           :default => false
  end




  create_table "discussions", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "content"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
  end
```

Comment: Why do you want to create a micropost if you have saved it already?

Answer (score 1):

The `create!` method basically  runs a `new` and then a `save!` throwing a validation exception if there is one.

When you write this:

```
@micropost = current_user.microposts.build(params[:micropost])
```

It initializes (normally) a new micropost with the current_user id as if you had run:

```
@micropost = Micropost.new(params[:micropost].merge(user_id: current_user.id))
```

And `@micropost.save` saves it... Which in short does exactly the same as your `create!` method.

In conclusion I think you should delete this line:

```
@micropost = Micropost.create!(params[:micropost])
```

Comment: If there is an error, ``save!`` will throw an exception, not return an error !

Comment: how about for Discussion? I get this error `Validation failed: User can't be blank` when I try to create. How can I save the user_id?

Comment: As you did with microposts... `@thread = current_user.discussions.build(params[:discussion])` and then `@thread.save`

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
@thread = Discussion.create!(params[:micropost])
```

To:

```
@thread = current_user.discussions.create(params[:micropost])
```

This will get you the `user_id`

However... I think your controller is trying to "do too much".  If this is the create action for `microposts` Why would it create a `discussion` and *not* a `micropost`?

Also if there are validation errors in that `@micropost.save` the user won't get any feedback, it'll just fail silently.  Same goes for the discussion create, you don't want them to get the generic http status 500 error page "Something went wrong" when the discussion fails validation when you use the `create!` method.

Comment: I originally just wanted to have microposts. However, I installed the PublicActivity gem which tracks a model (micropost in my case) and I can have it on the front page of some activity happening on my site. If it was a micropost, I want the text of publicactivity to be different from if micropost.review was checked. I ended up creating another separate model called Discussion to track it separately. I'm looking into ways to just use the micropost model and track two parts of it (review checked or not). If you know any ways I can do that, please let me know